# Splash screen on android mobile app does not hide

Tags: java, android, react-native, splash-screen

I'm setting up a splash screen for my react native mobile app. On Android, my splash screen shows up but then stays there instead of going after sometime.

I'm using React Native Splash Screen `v3.1.1` for displaying the splash screen.

My `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

My `MainActivity.java`

```java
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "my_app_name";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

My `app/res/layout/launch_screen.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_splash"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run the app, I see the splash screen (`@drawable/background_splash` is visible on the screen) but the screen stays there instead of going away after sometime.

In the ideal case, I want to see the login screen after the splash screen fades.

Just in case it helps:
If I comment-out the following lines from `MainActivity.java` then I can see the login screen but without the splash screen.

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Also, I've place `SplashScreen.hide()` in my `SignIn` screen's `componentDidMount()`.

Edit: Adding my `MainApplication.java` code

```java
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new SplashScreenReactPackage(),
            new RNGoogleSigninPackage(),
            new RNGestureHandlerPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new ImagePickerPackage(),
            new SQLitePluginPackage()

      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

ADB LogCat:

```
2019-01-20 12:19:16.231 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru/lib-main flags = 1]
2019-01-20 12:19:16.234 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru/lib-main
2019-01-20 12:19:16.236 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: deps mismatch on deps store: regenerating
2019-01-20 12:19:16.237 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: so store dirty: regenerating
2019-01-20 12:19:16.314 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libfb.so: deferring to libdir
2019-01-20 12:19:16.314 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libfolly_json.so: deferring to libdir
2019-01-20 12:19:16.324 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libglog.so: deferring to libdir
2019-01-20 12:19:16.324 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libglog_init.so: deferring to libdir
2019-01-20 12:19:16.324 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libgnustl_shared.so: deferring to libdir
2019-01-20 12:19:16.324 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libicu_common.so: deferring to libdir
2019-01-20 12:19:16.324 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libimagepipeline.so: deferring to libdir
2019-01-20 12:19:16.324 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libjsc.so: deferring to libdir
2019-01-20 12:19:16.324 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libprivatedata.so: deferring to libdir
2019-01-20 12:19:16.324 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libreactnativejni.so: deferring to libdir
2019-01-20 12:19:16.324 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libyoga.so: deferring to libdir
2019-01-20 12:19:16.324 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: regenerating DSO store com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource
2019-01-20 12:19:16.325 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: Finished regenerating DSO store com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource
2019-01-20 12:19:16.326 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: starting syncer worker
2019-01-20 12:19:16.336 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru/lib-main (from syncer thread)
2019-01-20 12:19:16.337 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: not releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru/lib-main (syncer thread started)
2019-01-20 12:19:16.337 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: init finish: 4 SO sources prepared
2019-01-20 12:19:16.337 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: init exiting
2019-01-20 12:19:16.411 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-01-20 12:19:16.431 1714-1771/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-01-20 12:19:16.474 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
2019-01-20 12:19:16.474 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: init exiting
2019-01-20 12:19:16.520 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-01-20 12:19:16.528 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/w.mysankalptar: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, reflection)
2019-01-20 12:19:16.528 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/w.mysankalptar: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-01-20 12:19:16.528 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/w.mysankalptar: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-01-20 12:19:16.568 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
2019-01-20 12:19:16.568 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
2019-01-20 12:19:16.643 8124-8146/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ReconnectingWebSocket: Couldn't connect to "ws://10.0.2.2:8081/message?device=Android%20SDK%20built%20for%20x86%20-%209%20-%20API%2028&app=com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru&clientid=DevSupportManagerImpl", will silently retry
2019-01-20 12:19:16.645 8124-8145/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ReactNative: The packager does not seem to be running as we got an IOException requesting its status: Failed to connect to /10.0.2.2:8081
2019-01-20 12:19:16.649 1574-1574/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
2019-01-20 12:19:16.659 1574-1574/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
2019-01-20 12:19:16.668 1574-1574/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
2019-01-20 12:19:16.670 1869-2740/system_process I/GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@a2c47bd)
2019-01-20 12:19:16.670 1869-1885/system_process I/GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@a2c47bd)
2019-01-20 12:19:16.672 8124-8148/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:InspectorPackagerConnection: Couldn't connect to packager, will silently retry
2019-01-20 12:19:16.682 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ReactNative: Packager connection already open, nooping.
2019-01-20 12:19:16.718 8124-8141/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-01-20 12:19:16.718 8124-8141/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-01-20 12:19:16.718 8124-8141/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-01-20 12:19:16.718 8124-8141/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-01-20 12:19:16.719 8124-8141/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-01-20 12:19:16.719 8124-8141/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-01-20 12:19:16.722 8124-8141/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xcd56d360: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2019-01-20 12:19:16.725 8124-8141/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcd56d360: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xde56f120)
2019-01-20 12:19:16.729 1714-1771/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-01-20 12:19:16.879 1714-1714/? D/SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: changing com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru/com.sankalptaru.MainActivity to com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru/com.sankalptaru.MainActivity#1
2019-01-20 12:19:16.884 1574-1574/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
2019-01-20 12:19:16.898 1574-1628/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
2019-01-20 12:19:16.906 1574-1628/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
2019-01-20 12:19:16.923 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundFromBundleLoader()
2019-01-20 12:19:16.923 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
2019-01-20 12:19:16.923 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
2019-01-20 12:19:16.934 8124-8141/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcd56d360: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xde56f120)
2019-01-20 12:19:16.958 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: About to load: libreactnativejni.so
2019-01-20 12:19:16.962 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru/lib-main
2019-01-20 12:19:16.963 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so found on /data/app/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru-AjWaPo-Bi1Ax60FcLjJKDA==/lib/x86
2019-01-20 12:19:16.963 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libreactnativejni.so
2019-01-20 12:19:17.055 8124-8141/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcd56d360: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xde56f120)
2019-01-20 12:19:17.081 1869-1894/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru/com.sankalptaru.MainActivity: +2s398ms
2019-01-20 12:19:17.082 8124-8141/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcd56d360: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xde56f120)
2019-01-20 12:19:17.097 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: Loaded: libreactnativejni.so
2019-01-20 12:19:17.099 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: About to load: libfb.so
2019-01-20 12:19:17.099 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru/lib-main
2019-01-20 12:19:17.099 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: libfb.so found on /data/app/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru-AjWaPo-Bi1Ax60FcLjJKDA==/lib/x86
2019-01-20 12:19:17.099 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libfb.so
2019-01-20 12:19:17.101 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: About to load: libfb.so
2019-01-20 12:19:17.101 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru/lib-main
2019-01-20 12:19:17.101 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: libfb.so found on /data/app/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru-AjWaPo-Bi1Ax60FcLjJKDA==/lib/x86
2019-01-20 12:19:17.101 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libfb.so
2019-01-20 12:19:17.101 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/w.mysankalptar: Thread[20,tid=8150,Native,Thread*=0xcd57aa00,peer=0x1638a310,"Thread-2"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru-AjWaPo-Bi1Ax60FcLjJKDA==/lib/x86/libfb.so"
2019-01-20 12:19:17.101 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: Loaded: libfb.so
2019-01-20 12:19:17.101 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: Loaded: libfb.so
2019-01-20 12:19:17.102 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
2019-01-20 12:19:17.140 8124-8141/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcd56d360: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xde56f120)
2019-01-20 12:19:17.166 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupViewManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.167 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupShadowNode
2019-01-20 12:19:17.181 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeViewManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.181 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeShadowNode
2019-01-20 12:19:17.183 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextViewManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.183 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextShadowNode
2019-01-20 12:19:17.183 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.checkbox.ReactCheckBoxManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.187 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode
2019-01-20 12:19:17.197 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDialogPickerManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.200 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.201 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDropdownPickerManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.203 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollViewManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.208 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollContainerViewManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.211 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.214 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarShadowNode
2019-01-20 12:19:17.216 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollViewManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.219 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.221 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager$ReactSliderShadowNode
2019-01-20 12:19:17.224 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.231 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager$ReactSwitchShadowNode
2019-01-20 12:19:17.233 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.toolbar.ReactToolbarManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.236 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.webview.ReactWebViewManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.244 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.swiperefresh.SwipeRefreshLayoutManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.250 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.250 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewShadowNode
2019-01-20 12:19:17.251 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageViewManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.254 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageShadowNode
2019-01-20 12:19:17.257 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.262 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ReactModalHostManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.266 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ModalHostShadowNode
2019-01-20 12:19:17.268 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.269 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextShadowNode
2019-01-20 12:19:17.270 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.278 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputShadowNode
2019-01-20 12:19:17.285 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.289 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextShadowNode
2019-01-20 12:19:17.295 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.304 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.viewpager.ReactViewPagerManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.304 1714-1775/? W/SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to set client state on removed layer: Splash Screen com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru#0
2019-01-20 12:19:17.304 1714-1775/? W/SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to destroy on removed layer: Splash Screen com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru#0
2019-01-20 12:19:17.308 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextViewManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.309 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextShadowNode
2019-01-20 12:19:17.310 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninButtonViewManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.311 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerRootViewManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.312 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager
2019-01-20 12:19:17.362 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
2019-01-20 12:19:17.364 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
2019-01-20 12:19:17.374 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
2019-01-20 12:19:17.374 8124-8150/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
2019-01-20 12:19:17.382 8124-8153/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
2019-01-20 12:19:17.382 8124-8153/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
2019-01-20 12:19:17.386 8124-8153/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
2019-01-20 12:19:17.386 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/unknown:ReactNative: Packager connection already open, nooping.
2019-01-20 12:19:17.391 8124-8153/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: About to load: libyoga.so
2019-01-20 12:19:17.392 8124-8153/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: libyoga.so not found on /data/data/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru/lib-main
2019-01-20 12:19:17.392 8124-8153/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: libyoga.so found on /data/app/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru-AjWaPo-Bi1Ax60FcLjJKDA==/lib/x86
2019-01-20 12:19:17.392 8124-8153/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libyoga.so
2019-01-20 12:19:17.398 8124-8153/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: Loaded: libyoga.so
2019-01-20 12:19:17.422 8124-8153/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: init exiting
2019-01-20 12:19:17.598 8124-8152/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/ReactNativeJS: 'Setting debug to:', false
2019-01-20 12:19:17.598 8124-8152/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/ReactNativeJS: Promise based runtime ready
2019-01-20 12:19:17.601 8124-8152/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/ReactNativeJS: OPEN database: sankalptaru_v4
2019-01-20 12:19:17.606 8124-8152/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/chatty: uid=10067(com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru) mqt_js identical 2 lines
2019-01-20 12:19:17.606 8124-8152/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/ReactNativeJS: OPEN database: sankalptaru_v4
2019-01-20 12:19:17.674 1869-2740/system_process I/GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@3577a57)
2019-01-20 12:19:17.674 1869-1885/system_process I/GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@3577a57)
2019-01-20 12:19:17.730 8124-8152/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/ReactNativeJS: creating tables
2019-01-20 12:19:17.730 8124-8152/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/ReactNativeJS: creating tables
2019-01-20 12:19:17.733 8124-8152/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/ReactNativeJS: Running application "sankalptaru" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === false, development-level warning are OFF, performance optimizations are ON
2019-01-20 12:19:17.767 8124-8152/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/ReactNativeJS: token fetched
2019-01-20 12:19:17.773 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/w.mysankalptar: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/View;->mAccessibilityDelegate:Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (light greylist, reflection)
2019-01-20 12:19:17.791 8124-8152/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/ReactNativeJS: SQL executed fine
2019-01-20 12:19:17.791 8124-8152/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/chatty: uid=10067(com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru) mqt_js identical 2 lines
2019-01-20 12:19:17.791 8124-8152/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/ReactNativeJS: SQL executed fine
2019-01-20 12:19:17.819 8124-8158/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
2019-01-20 12:19:18.002 8124-8135/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/w.mysankalptar: Background concurrent copying GC freed 39669(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 7(156KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 2MB/4MB, paused 441us total 157.994ms
2019-01-20 12:19:18.005 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/SignInButton: Sign in button not found, using placeholder instead
2019-01-20 12:19:18.030 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru I/chatty: uid=10067(com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru) identical 3 lines
2019-01-20 12:19:18.034 8124-8124/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru W/SignInButton: Sign in button not found, using placeholder instead
2019-01-20 12:19:18.056 8124-8161/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: About to load: libimagepipeline.so
2019-01-20 12:19:18.056 8124-8161/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: libimagepipeline.so not found on /data/data/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru/lib-main
2019-01-20 12:19:18.057 8124-8161/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: libimagepipeline.so found on /data/app/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru-AjWaPo-Bi1Ax60FcLjJKDA==/lib/x86
2019-01-20 12:19:18.057 8124-8161/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libimagepipeline.so
2019-01-20 12:19:18.086 8124-8161/com.coloredcow.mysankalptaru D/SoLoader: Loaded: libimagepipeline.so
2019-01-20 12:19:18.675 1869-2740/system_process I/GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@9cfc944)
2019-01-20 12:19:18.675 1869-1885/system_process I/GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@9cfc944)
2019-01-20 12:19:19.676 1869-2740/system_process I/GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@b639a2d)
2019-01-20 12:19:19.677 1869-1885/system_process I/GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@b639a2d)
```

Comment: I dont see your MainApplication code. Post that and also post the adb lgocat *:E output to see any java errors.

Comment: @sfratini I've added my MainApplication and LogCat

Comment: did you checked adb logs ?  it can stuck if there is an error. ( sorry I didnt refresh page a long time :))

Comment: Did you hide the SplashScreen in react native using SplashScreen.hide();

Comment: @AshwinMothilal yes, I've mentioned that in my question itself

Comment: Comment this and see SplashScreen.show(this); because if you get some JS error on the signin component it won't hide.

Comment: @Abhishek did u manage to resolve it?

Comment: Yes @KimberleeHo

Comment: @Abhishek do u mind sharing the solution? im having the same issue. it seems like the onCreate in mainActivity.js is causing react native not to run.

Comment: @KimberleeHo, Abhishek

Hey, I face with exact same issue. Could you tell me how did you resolve the problem?